# Is there a way to match patterns from one column to other one?

Tags: string, postgresql, string-matching

I want to use club position and check if preferred_position contain the string then return True/False value for each row.

| Club_position | Preferred_position |
| --- | --- |
| RM | RM/LW |
| RCB | RB |
| LW | RM/LW |
| CMD | RM/RCM |
| ST | ST |
| ST | ST/LW |

I used LIKE() but it returned false when it didn't match exactly
as an example: ST = ST/LW returned as false
I want my output like

- True
- False
- True
- False
- True
- True

  UPDATE FROM "Football"
  SET desired_position = "Club_Position" LIKE "Preferred_Position";

It did not work.

Data types are text. I also tried changing them to varchar. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use concat.

```
UPDATE "Football"
SET "Desired_Position" = "Preferred_Position" LIKE CONCAT('%', "Club_Position", '%');
```